# what does caret do in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, caret

I'm playing hackthebox machine's and current one has a postgresql db in place. The query breaks with ' and appeas as follows:

> ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "'" LINE 1: Select * from
> cars where name ilike '%**test'**%' ^

I understand  that % is being used to search within the query string for the characters provided but, What is ^ used for?

Bold highlights my test query

All my searches yielded resulst regarding regexes and caret signaling the start of the string. Plus other result about using cli or something like that.

Can anybody tell me what is it doing at the end of the query?

Comment: Generally in Postgres error messages `^` points at the location of the error.

Comment: Can you post the exact, line-by-line output of the error message (and maybe even a screenshot in addition)? The caret character is normally not part of the query, it's part of the error message.

Comment: Thanks guys, in my case the answer was the reply from jjanes and Adrian. It is pointing the error ocurred in the last line (odd number of quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are looking for the use of the caret specifically within error messages.

If I run this query:

```
psql -c " Select * from cars where name ilike '%test'%'"
```

This is what I get, preserving line breaks and spaces:

```
ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'"
LINE 1:  Select * from cars where name ilike '%test'%'
                                                     ^
```

The caret points to where on the previous line the error occurred.  In this case, that is where the opening quote mark that never got closed was located.

If you are using a tool which malformats your error messages, you should consider changing to one that does not or otherwise figuring out how to fix it.